# Summarise data frame by group column, using column-specific summary stats

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person = c(123L, 123L, 123L), Start.Time = c("2023-06-18 12:22:00", 
"2023-06-18 10:22:00", "2023-06-18 06:22:00"), End.Time = c("2023-06-19 15:41:00", 
"2023-06-19 05:41:00", "2023-06-19 15:30:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I want to only keep one row per patient (group by patient ID) to where it selects the minimum `start.time` and maximum `end.time`.
The result should look like this:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Person = c(123L, NA, NA), Start.Time = c("2023-06-18 06:22:00"), End.Time = c("2023-06-19 15:41:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about (d being your data):

```
library(dplyr)

d |> 
  summarise(Start.Time = min(Start.Time, na.rm = TRUE),
            End.Time = max(End.Time, na.rm = TRUE),
            .by = Person
            )
```

```
  Person          Start.Time            End.Time
1    123 2023-06-18 06:22:00 2023-06-19 15:41:00
```